# What do the square brackets in the following React test do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm reading "Mastering React Test-Driven Development", and one of the refactorings the book recommends is extracting a common test into a helper function, by changing this:

```
it('saves existing first name when submitted', async () => {
  expect.hasAssertions();
  render(<CustomerForm {...{firstName: 'Ashley'}} onSubmit={(customer) => 
  expect(customer.firstName).toEqual('Ashley')} />);
  await ReactTestUtils.Simulate.submit(form('customer'));
});

it('saves existing last name when submitted', async () => {
  expect.hasAssertions();
  render(<CustomerForm {...{lastName: 'Jones'}} onSubmit={(customer) => 
  expect(customer.lastName).toEqual('Jones')} />);
  await ReactTestUtils.Simulate.submit(form('customer'));
});
```

...to this:

```
const itSavesExistingValueWhenSubmitted = (fieldName, fieldValue) => {
  it('saves existing value when submitted', async () => {
    expect.hasAssertions();
    render(<CustomerForm {...{[fieldName]: fieldValue}} onSubmit={(props) => 
    expect(props[fieldName]).toEqual(fieldValue)} />);
    await ReactTestUtils.Simulate.submit(form('customer'));
  });
}

itSavesExistingValueWhenSubmitted('firstName', 'Ashley');
itSavesExistingValueWhenSubmitted('lastName', 'Jones');
```

My question is about the code snippet `{...{[fieldName]: fieldValue}}` in the refactored test.  I get that the `...` is a spread attribute for the subsequent `{}` object.  But why does  `fieldName` need to be wrapped in square brackets?  What is the grammar here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{...{[fieldName]: fieldValue}}
```

Here `[fieldName]` is a computed property name. Computed property name is a feature that allows to use a value of a variable as a property name.

So when you pass `fieldName` as `"firstName"`, `"firstName"` will be used as the property name, whereas if you omit `[]`, the property name will literally be `"fieldName"` not the value of `fieldName`.

This is a feature of ES6. Refer [this](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-object-creation-356e504173a8) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets is used to evaluate the object key in ES6.
You can do this way, for example:

```
var person = {};
var key = "name";

person[key] = "John";

console.log(person); // should print  Object { name="John"}
```

But if you are using ES6 you can do the following to set the object:

```
var key = "name";

var person = {[key]:"John"};

console.log(person); // should print  Object { name="John"}
```